# Running website from a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a few websites hosted using shared hosting. The "primary domain" is hosted in the `/public_html` directory. What I want to do is run it from `/public_html/domain.com`. Here is my `/public_html/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain.com/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain.com/index.html [L]
```

Generally this works well, except when I attempt to access a directory, say `http://www.domain.com/test`, whereby I am redirected to `http://www.domain.com/domain.com/test`. To clarify, there should be no redirections, the server should simply serve the site from the specified subdirectory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /domain.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain.com/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain.com/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the error I am getting when I try to use the rules with RewriteBase: `The requested URL /[site folder name]/[site folder name]/index.html was not found on this server.`. Keep in mind that the `.htaccess` is in `/public_html`.