# Internal rewrite to remove directory from url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've searched and tried many tutorials and problem solutions but couldn't achieve what I want.

If user open `domain.com/xxx.php` he see the content of `domain.com/hosting/xxx.php`

This
`RewriteRule ^xxx.php$ /hosting/xxx.php`

Works perfectly what i want to do, but there are over 150 pages in `hosting` directory and writing rules for each page does not seem right? any possible way to do it dynamically?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640025/remove-directory-from-image-path-htaccess?rq=1) solution it works but it try to find those pages which are currently at root `domain.com/xxx.php` inside `domain.com/hosting/`

I search slimier questions have been asked many times before but non of the answer worked for me.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602537/running-website-from-a-subfolder

Comment: @CBroe no he is running website from a subfolder the problem is completely different

Answer (score 0):

You need to also take care of reuests to the shortened, rewritten URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?hosting/(.*)$ /$1 [END,NC,R=302]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /hosting/$1 [END]
```

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you are not looking at an older result that is cached on the client side. So _always_ test using a fresh anonymous browser window, always make _deep_ reloads (CTRL-R).

Comment: yes i removed the cache, `RewriteRule ^xxx.php$ /hosting/xxx.php` works for me but i will have to create this rule for all pages inside "hosting" folder, any way to achive this dynamically? the above code give me 404.

Comment: As said: the above works for me, so I can't really help with the 404 you observe. You'd need to take a look into your http server's log file, maybe enable rewrite logging.

Comment: Certainly such rules can work dynamic for any request / file, actually the rule I posted will work for _all_ files inside the folder.